# How to get an array from a C function in Swift?

Tags: swift, interop, unsafe-pointers

I am working with a C function in my Swift code that outputs an array. The function doesn't return an array because, apparently in C, functions are discouraged from returning arrays. Therefore, the function takes an `in-out` parameter (as a pointer) and places the array there.

The C function:

```
void kRing(H3Index origin, int k, H3Index* out);
```

`H3Index*` is the `out` parameter that takes the array. However, how do I get the array from this function in Swift? `H3Index*`, the `out` parameter, points to an integer. And, apparently in C, you can point to an integer, pass that pointer to a function, and that function can place an array in that pointer's place (even though it's pointing to an integer).

But because of Swift's type safety, this makes it difficult to get the array from the function. The Swift version:

```
kRing(origin: H3Index, k: Int32, out: UnsafeMutablePointer<H3Index>!)
```

My Swift implementation:

```
let h3Index: H3Index = 600022775385554943 // integer
let k: Int32 = 2 // integer
var result = H3Index() // the in-out parameter (must be integer to satisfy Swift's type safety)
_ = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result) { kRing(h3Index, k, $0) }
print(result)
```

And it prints the result (with a bad access error, which I don't care about right now). But the result is an integer when it should be an array. How is this done?

The C implementation, for reference:

```
H3Index indexed = 0x8a2a1072b59ffffL; // 64-integer (hex)
int k = 2; // integer
int maxNeighboring = maxKringSize(k); // integer

H3Index* neighboring = calloc(maxNeighboring, sizeof(H3Index)); // the out parameter (a pointer to an integer and/or array)

kRing(indexed, k, neighboring); // the function

for (int i = 0; i < maxNeighboring; i++) {
    if (neighboring[i] != 0) {
        // iterate through array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C,

```
H3Index* neighboring = calloc(maxNeighboring, sizeof(H3Index));
kRing(indexed, k, neighboring);
```

allocates memory for `maxNeighboring` elements of type `H3Index` and initializes the memory to zero. The address of that memory block (which is the address of the first element) is then passed to the `kRing` function.

It *is* possible to call `calloc` and `free` from Swift, but the easier to use API is `Unsafe(Mutable)(Buffer)Pointer` with its `allocate()` and `deallocate()` methods:

```
let neighboring = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<H3Index>.allocate(capacity: maxNeighboring)
neighboring.initialize(repeating: 0)
kRing(indexed, k, neighboring.baseAddress)
```

Now you can print the values with

```
for i in 0..<maxNeighboring { print(neighboring[i]) }
```

or justs (because `Unsafe(Mutable)BufferPointer` is a *collection* that can be iterated over):

```
for neighbor in neighboring { print(neighbor) }
```

Eventually you must release the memory to avoid a memory leak:

```
neighboring.deallocate()
```

A simpler solution is to define a Swift *array,* and pass the address of the element storage to the C function:

```
var neighboring = Array<H3Index>(repeating: 0, count: maxNeighboring)
kRing(indexed, k, &neighboring)

for neighbor in neighboring { print(neighbor) }
```

`neighboring` is a local variable now, so that the memory is automatically released when the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: Whatever they're paying you, it's not enough. How did you know that the Swift compiler would allow an array (as an in-out parameter) to be passed as an argument into a function that was expecting an `UnsafeMutablePointer` to an integer? I think of Swift as incredibly type safe and didn't even think to try to handle the function like it was intended because of the mismatching types.

Comment: @hgale: It is documented (but difficult to find). In https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/manual_memory_management/calling_functions_with_pointer_parameters: *When you call a function that is declared as taking an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>` argument, you can pass any of the following: ... An in-out expression of type `[Type]`  ... which is passed as a pointer to the start of the array, ...*

Comment: That's an impressive documentation reference, I really appreciate you. One last thing (for now), Swift is a distant, almost unrelated, cousin to C (given its relationship to Objective-C). Would it be correct to say that Swift made life a lot easier for programmers by shedding a lot of quirky C behavior but, under the hood, still works in a lot of ways like C?